# Assign unique ID based on instances of a pattern

Tags: r

I have chat logs from an experiment that are exported in this format:

```
df = data.frame(
   subject = c("string",1,2,3,"string", 2, 3, "string", 1,1,3,4),
   text = c(rep("blah blah blah", 12)), 
   period = c(rep("NA", 12))
  )

> head(df)
  subject           text period
  1  string blah blah blah     NA
  2       1 blah blah blah     NA
  3       2 blah blah blah     NA
  4       3 blah blah blah     NA
  5  string blah blah blah     NA
  6       2 blah blah blah     NA
```

where "string" is some identifier text repeated throughout the column.

I want to write a function that a) recognizes the character pattern in the `subject` column and b) assigns a value to `period` based on each instance of the pattern.

For example, I know that I can achieve the first part by running

```
> grepl("s+", df$subject, perl = T)
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and from there achieve the second part by running something that assigns `period == 1` for the first of instance of `TRUE`, `period == 2` for the second instance of `TRUE`, and so on. However I can't figure out this second part. Any ideas?

Comment: How will your desired output look like? For example, does `cumsum(grepl("s+", df$subject))` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure regarding your desired output, but assuming you don't have the `period` column (you made it a empty factor column which values is harder to change), using `data.table` you could simply do

```
df = data.frame(
  subject = c("string",1:3,"string", 2:3, "string", 1,1,3,4),
  text = "blah blah blah"
)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grep("s+", subject), period := seq_len(.N)]
df
#     subject           text period
#  1:  string blah blah blah      1
#  2:       1 blah blah blah     NA
#  3:       2 blah blah blah     NA
#  4:       3 blah blah blah     NA
#  5:  string blah blah blah      2
#  6:       2 blah blah blah     NA
#  7:       3 blah blah blah     NA
#  8:  string blah blah blah      3
#  9:       1 blah blah blah     NA
# 10:       1 blah blah blah     NA
# 11:       3 blah blah blah     NA
# 12:       4 blah blah blah     NA
```

What this basically does is to subset only by the matched instances, then take the length of the subset using the `.N` operator (which is 3 in this case), and assign *by reference* (using the `:=` operator) the sequence of 3 which is `1,2,3` to the `period` column within the subset.

---

Unless you just want

```
cumsum(grepl("s+", df$subject))
## [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

This, is just a modification of your solution which is basically converts your logical vector to a binary one (`TRUE` becomes 1 and `FALSE` becomes 0) and then performs a cumulative sum.

Comment: Thanks very much. @David Arenburg. Both answers work nicely, though I don't understand how they work. The problem appears to be much simpler than I thought. Please could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @invictus added an explanation.